# Using Handlebars with Deno v1.6.x

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, deno, oak

I'm struggling to get the Handlebars templating working with Deno v1.6.x, any thoughts?

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.6.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 8.8.278.2
typescript 4.1.3

$ tree
.
├── template.js
└── views
    ├── layouts
    │   └── main.hbs
    └── partials
```

```js
/* template.js */

import { Application, Router, Status } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'
import { Handlebars } from 'https://deno.land/x/handlebars/mod.ts'

const port = 8080

const app = new Application()
const router = new Router()
const handle = new Handlebars()

// error handler
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  try {
    await next()
  } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
  }
})

// the routes defined here
router.get('/', async context => {
    const data = {
    title: 'Fools Day',
    date: '01/04/20'
  }
    context.response.body = await handle.renderView('main', data)
})

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

// static content
app.use(async (context, next) => {
    const root = `${Deno.cwd()}/static`
    try {
        await context.send({ root })
    } catch {
        next()
    }
})

// page not found
app.use( async context => {
    context.response.status = Status.NotFound
  context.response.body = `"${context.request.url}" not found`
})

app.addEventListener("listen", ({ port }) => console.log(`listening on port: ${port}`) )

await app.listen({ port })
```

I get the following error when I try to view the page:

```
$ deno run --allow-net --unstable template.js
Check file:///home/xxx/template.js
listening on port: 8080
NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)
    at processResponse (deno:core/core.js:223:11)
    at Object.jsonOpAsync (deno:core/core.js:240:12)
    at async open (deno:runtime/js/30_files.js:44:17)
    at async readFile (deno:runtime/js/40_read_file.js:15:18)
    at async Handlebars.render (mod.ts:98:53)
    at async Handlebars.renderView (mod.ts:76:26)
    at async file:///home/xxx/template.js:28:26
    at async dispatch (middleware.ts:41:7)
    at async dispatch (middleware.ts:41:7)
    at async dispatch (middleware.ts:41:7)
```

I've looked at the documentation at https://deno.land/x/handlebars@v0.6.0 and think I have used all the default settings but the error message doesn't tell me **what** file is not found.

Has anyone had experience using Handlebars with Deno?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Make sure you have a layout file according to your default layout!!

If you do not want a default layout file then you can do this:

```
const handle = new Handlebars({defaultLayout:''});
```

Here's the [code](https://deno.land/x/handlebars@v0.6.0/mod.ts#L51) for renderView

```
  public async renderView(
    view: string,
    context?: Record<string, unknown>,
    layout?: string,
  ): Promise<string> {
    if (!view) {
      console.warn("View is null");
      return "";
    }

    const config: HandlebarsConfig = this.config as HandlebarsConfig;

    const partialsPathes = await this.getTemplatesPath(
      join(config.baseDir, config.partialsDir),
    );
    partialsPathes && (await this.registerPartials(partialsPathes));

    const path = join(config.baseDir, view + config.extname);
    const body: string = await this.render(path, context);

    layout = (layout as string) || config.defaultLayout;

    if (layout) {
      const layoutPath: string = join(
        config.baseDir,
        config.layoutsDir,
        layout + config.extname,
      );

      return this.render(layoutPath, { ...context, body });
    }

    return body;
  }
```

The first parameter, in your case `main` tells the code to look for a file called `main.hbs` in your `views` directory (provided you are using the default config).

You can additionally pass a layout parameter to render it within a layout file that is housed in your layouts directory.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that was what what my code is doing. I'm passing the layout parameter of `main` and the handlebars file is in the default `views/` directory. Can you explain what path I've got wrong because I'm struggling to see it. I've included the project structure at the top.

Comment: @MarkTyers you’re passing the view parameter as main, not the layout parameter. Read the code. Move your main file up one level into the views directory and it will work

Comment: That was where I placed it originally and it didn't work.

Comment: @MarkTyers Are you using the default config?

Comment: yes, I posted the script I'm running in the original post. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkTyers you're missing a default layout file. The default layout file is `main.hbs` and it lives in layouts. If you do not want a default layout file, then instantiate your handlerbars with an empty value for `defaultLayout` To be clear, you're trying to render the view (views/main.hbs) and handlebars is rendering it into the layout given by defaultLayout (which is main) so it can't find `views/layouts/main.hbs` - which is the default layout file.

Comment: Cheers @Adam, page now displays but always uses the `/views/layouts/main.hbs` regardless of which template I specify in the `renderView()` function. Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: @MarkTyers see my edit to the answer. It’s the defaultLayout in the default config. If you don’t want one, set the defaultLayout to an empty string. If you want to use a different one, pass the third parameter to renderView

Comment: Many thanks. I'm trying to get to grips with Deno and Oak this week and struggle with the lack of documentation. I've marked this answer as correct.

Comment: adding `./views/layouts/main.hbs` doesn't work for me either.